# Is there a replacement for Arrays with enums as indexes?

Tags: java, c, enums

I used to use enums as indexes in C. (each enum something like an alias for an int value)
Example:

```
typedef enum {DOG, CAT, MOUSE} ANIMALS;
int[3] age;
...
age[DOG] = 4;
age[CAT] = 3;
age[MOUSE] = 10;
```

With enums as indexes, I can always be sure that I am updating the right cell. Furthermore, I need the simplicity of arrays as well.

I would like to do the same in Java. But, I cant seem to find a simple replacement.
Does anyone know a replacement that can be used the same way as Array+enum combo did in C?

Comment: Why? Use `Map` and `List`.

Comment: You need to show a small example of what exactly you're trying to achieve and where and how you want to use the enums. As such, your question really doesn't make much sense to a Java developer with little or no knowledge about `C`.

Comment: I think that doesn't exists. But if it does, it should be a bad practice, remember that java is an object oriented language. Also note, that in C that is not a good practice to (you should think about data type abstraction). Unless you want to do something like key-value, in that case you can use a Map.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments, I will read up more on Maps..etc to see if it fits my requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is a fairly simple one. Use [HashMaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

```
Map<CustomEnum, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

//Basic usage
hashMap.put(CustomEnumID, ObjectValue);
ObjectValue obj = hashMap.get(CustumEnumID); //Returns the value from the above line
hashMap.containsValue(CustomEnumID); //Return true or false
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Let me read up, then re-comment. But just to make sure, do you mean that CustomEnumID will be a custom enum that I create, and it will simply act as my index as you kindly instructed above?

Comment: For lack of a better general term I used `CustomEnumID`. But yes, `CustumEnumID` would be a custom enum class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tested it, and it worked : ) I am starting to love this website : p

Comment: No prob, and yeah I love this site too!

Answer (score 1):

*Enum* is pretty much object in Java. So basically you go for *HashMap* is you would like to introduce Object-Object relations in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As was already said in other answers, using `Map<YourEnum, V>` is a good way to do what you want to do. However, Java, actually, has a [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) (it does implement regular `Map` interface) which is designed especially for use with enum type keys, and, as said in the documentation, it is likely to be faster than using `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two solutions:

1) You can simulate 'C enum type' by class in Java:

```
class Animals {
    public static int DOG = 0;
    public static int CAT = 1;
    public static int MOUSE = 2;
}
```

In this case you manually set values to enum - in C it is automatically done by compiler.

Usage of enum looks like this

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] age = new int[3];

    age[Animals.DOG] = 4;
    age[Animals.CAT] = 3;
    age[Animals.MOUSE] = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(age[i] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

I think this is bad solution because this break OOP principle of encapsulation (in class Animals).

2) You can use Java enum

```
enum Animals {
    DOG(0), CAT(1), MOUSE(2);
    int value;

    private Animals(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And example of usage

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] age = new int[3];

        age[Animals.DOG.getValue()] = 4;
        age[Animals.CAT.getValue()] = 3;
        age[Animals.MOUSE.getValue()] = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(age[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

In Java enum is kind of class. For more details read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
There is no default values for enum and you have to set by yourself. In this example it is done with construcructor `Animal(int value)`. Also, we cannot use `Animals.DOG` like integer values but we have to use method `getValue()`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! But, I decided to go with the option DonyorM kindly provided.